# Operation Has Been Cancelled in Windows 7!

Tags: windows-7

I Use Windows 7.I am Not Administrator.I want run executable files in Windows ,but I can not do it,Because when I try System Has a Error:

"This Operation has been cancelled due to restriction in effect on this computer.please contact your system administrator".

I want Solve this problem,and I do not want contact my Administrator.
I try MMC And gpedit.msc but those do not work And I See this Error Again.

Please Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can't, that's the whole point of permissions.

Maybe if you were a bit more specific to *exactly* what you need there could be a workaround.